# Data binding in pivot TitleTemplate for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I must be missing something simple here...I am writing a Windows Phone 7 app and I have customized my pivot header to be the following:

```
<controls:Pivot Name="InfoPivot">
  <controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding CategoryFill}"  Height="50" Width="50" Margin="355,25,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="CategoryRect" />
        <StackPanel Margin="-425,-14,0,0" Width="432">
          <TextBlock x:Name="StationTitle" Text="{Binding StationTitle}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
          <TextBlock Name="LocationTitle" Text="{Binding LocationTitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
         </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

When I navigate to this page, I pass Station and Location as parameters, and in the OnNavigatedTo() for this page I try to set the StationTitle and LocationTitle. Unfortunately, I end up getting:

`Error 2 The name 'StationTitle' does not exist in the current context`

How should/do we go about accessing members in the Pivot TitleTemplate? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Shawn, Could you show us how you're declaring/passing the parameters?

Comment: From MainPage.xml in a SelectionChangedHandler:
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestInfoPivot.xaml?" + "Station=" + stationStr + "&Location=" + locationStr, UriKind.Relative));

I have verified that stationStr and locationStr has the correct values....then in TestInfoPivot.xaml I do

    string station = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Station", out station)) {
        StationTitle = station;
    }

similar for LocationTitle.

Comment: Do you see the correct values in StationTitle and LocationTitle after the QueryString code in TestInfoPivot executes? Hard to get a sense of this without seeing the blocks of code - it would be preferable if you could paste them into an edit of the original question.

Comment: When Providing additional details please edit you question rather placing them in a comment.  This is especially true when those details contain code because as you can see the code is barely readable a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Stop using the title template and binding to acheive this.  Try this instead:-

```
<controls:Pivot Name="InfoPivot">
   <controls:Pivot.Title>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <Rectangle Fill="{Binding CategoryFill}" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="355,25,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="CategoryRect" />
          <StackPanel Margin="-425,-14,0,0" Width="432">
              <TextBlock x:Name="StationTitle" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
              <TextBlock x:Name="LocationTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/> 
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
   </controls:Pivot.Title>
```

Then in code-behind:-

```
 if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Station", out station))
 {
     StationTitle.Text = station;
 }

 if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("LocationTitle", out locationTitle))
 {
     LocationTitle.Text = locationTitle;
 }
```

Comment: Weird, so TitleTemplate doesn't work?  Anyhow, this fixed my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of your code, this may be as simple as making the Name declaration consistent on your two TextBlocks.

Note, one is Name="", the other is x:Name="".

Comment: When the element has a `Name` property `x:Name` and `Name` are identical.  `TextBlock` does have a `Name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the template inline worked for me, The TitleTemplate just wouldn't work.

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <phone:Pivot.Title>
        <TextBlock Margin="0"
            Text="{Binding Exercise.Name}" 
            Style="{StaticResource MainTitleStyle}"/>
    </phone:Pivot.Title>
</phone:Pivot>
```